# Looking for additional tips for applying waterbased stain on dining table prior to epoxy coating

Tags: staining, sanding

Having problems with a staining project and after looking through some other examples on this site found what I thought was some good info in the answer ( [How to correct water based stain dried streaky](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/10121/how-to-correct-water-based-stain-dried-streaky?rq=1) ) and plan on that being the basis for starting the corrections but wanted find out a little more detail about that process/

The first thing it says to apply the stain to the entire surface all in one go all at once.  Not sure how this is possible without it drying out and causing a big mess so more elaboration would be great.

I was planning on prewetting the table again, but would it be better to put on a diluted stain instead?  If so what ratio?

How important is it to remove ALL the stain before starting over?  I don't think I have the time to remove all the stain and am okay with some variation in color.

UPDATE - Tried staining the whole table all in one go with a rag as suggested in that answer above and have a terrible stuck mess... good thing I was testing it on the underside of the table this time...  180 grit sand, prewetted surface, 5 minutes to rub the stain on and all dried out...

[image: Sanded top down again, ready to stain]

UPDATE2 - Flipped table over, sanded down most of the stain @ 180 and ready to try applying stain again... crossing fingers for better results!

[image: 1st Coat 1]
[image: 1st Coat 2]

UPDATE3 - Stained in 3" sections.  Not sure why the middle turned out darker than the edges...  Thinking of applying a 2nd coat just to the edges.  What does everyone think of how it looks so far?  OK?

[image: 2nd Coat 1]
[image: 2nd Coat 2]

UPDATE4 - 2nd coat stain on the lighter parts on the edge.  Think its as good as I'm going to get it with what I using anyway.  Thoughts?

Comment: ok, I can remove text/info and consolidate to a question or two.

Comment: Some staining products are more forgiving than others. For conventional waterbased stain, due to its fast drying it's challenging to get good results on large surfaces, *even for an experienced user*; you have to work very fast (hence the soaked rag and not a brush) and deftly because you may have only one chance to get it right. If you have no prior experience of this you may need to watch a video of a pro doing it (or at least see pictures from a good finishing book) so you can see or get a good impression of what the application stage is like.

Comment: Now, what stain product are you using exactly? If you're using something from a reliable and technically proficient company like General Finishes, they'll be able to give you guidance that might help. I'm aware you're running out of time, and I don't want to recommend going a different route as I'd normally do (other stain products may be *much* more forgiving) but if your first staining of the top doesn't go right you're unlikely to finish this in time. You don't have to finish the table to put it into service, this is a fairly durable hardwood and it *will* withstand normal use and cleaning.

Comment: So I'm using a Behr stain.  Unfortunately the mom & pop place didn't have any water based stains and the only water based stuff at the Home Depot was Behr... Probably should have tried the Woodworking store rather than the general hardware stores.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about possibly just using it as it for now until I get back.  Guess I was stuck in the mode get it done now or could damage it using it unfinished.  I'll attempt another go at the stain using the method that worked best for me (placing water down at the edges of where I'm going to end, and then do 3" swaths of the full table length) and if it doesn't work just use it as is until I return and go buy some General Finishes.

Comment: General Finishes was just one name that came to mind. Don't dismiss Behr, at least it's not Minwax :-D Typed a different Comment here just now because I hadn't seen the update. The current stain job is not bad at all! That's about as good a result as I think you can expect. If you had the time to continue now and just go through the finishing stage by stage until you were naturally done I'd have suggested a switch in product to help even up the colour. Layering different colouring products like this is commonly done, so it doesn't have to be seen as a failure of any kind.

Comment: *"Thanks for the advice about possibly just using it as it for now until I get back."* Just to be clear, I meant the tabletop sanded back to bare wood and just left at that stage. I think I can identify the wood your tabletop is made from and my in-laws have a table made from the same stuff. Over-enthusiastic cleaning of their table rubbed off the finish along the edges and the wood there has been *completely* bare for maybe 3-4 years and it has held up just fine! It has gone a little grubby, but that's easy enough to deal with down the road if necessary — appropriate cleaning + a light sand.

Comment: ok, i'm kinda thinking the same thing about it being the best I can hope for.  I'm thinking seal coat epoxy and then flood coat and can use it in a couple days.  Would you recommend a real light sanding before applying epoxy or does it matter?  Felt the surface and there are a couple of rough spots, but I wouldn't say the grain is raised.

Comment: You can do it and get away with it, but it is highly risky to sand stained wood. The penetration can be shockingly shallow in some areas and the risk of "sand-throughs" where you expose fresh wood is very high — it only takes one tiny spot to cause a big headache. Even if you did have raised grain, with a thick coating like epoxy it'll get completely buried in the finish (and it isn't visible either). Only 3-4 full-strength coats of varnish can be enough to bury raised grain, and poured epoxies are said to be equivalent to 17 coats of varnish or more.